# How to use load balancer for monolithic server

Tags: server, load-balancing

If a monolithic back end application gets billions of requests can we add load balancer ?
If so , how it works to reduce the load ?

Comment: Is the monolithic back end application stateless? IS it RESTful? Or require sessions to work properly?

Comment: I am just learning so the doubt , could you give me answer for both ??

Answer (score 3):

In order for a load balancer to be useful, it must be possible for your application to be spread across more than one "backend" server. The "purest" version of this setup is one where the backend servers are totally stateless and don't have any concept of a "connection" or "sessions" and each request will require approximately the same amount of work/resources. In this case, you can configure the loadbalancer to just randomly proxy requests to a pool of backend servers. An example of an application like this would be a static webserver.

Next, slightly less pure, would be those applications where the backend server doesn't need any particular state at the beginning of a "connection" or "session", but needs to maintain state while that sessions continues, and so each client needs to be assigned to the same server for the duration of that session. This slightly complicates things, as you then need "sticky" connections, and probably some way to pick the least-loaded servers to route new connections to, rather than doing it at random (since sessions will be of different lengths). An SMTP server is an example of this type.

The worst kind of application in this sense is one in which the backend server needs to maintain global state in order to be useful. A database server is the classic example. This kind of application is essentially impossible to load-balance without lots of trade-offs, and are usually the biggest, baddest servers that typical applications use, because it is often cheaper and easier, in terms of engineering, to simply buy the meanest, most expensive possible hardware, than it is to deal with the harsh realities of distributed systems, particularly if there are dependent systems (years of accumulated application code) that implicitly make assumptions about data integrity, etc. which cannot be met under, for example, the [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem).